# Consider defining a bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' in your configuration. Spring Boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-couchbase

Any help appreciated !

**I have a spring boot application to be connected to couchbase with following details**

1. Repository interface

   ```
    @Repository 
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository [Users,Strings] {

        List findByFullName(String fullName); 
    }
   ```
2. Controller class

   ```
    @RestController
    @Component
    public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public ResponseEntity addNewUser(@RequestBody Users user)
    {
    userRepository.save(user);
    }
   ```
3. Couchbase configs

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class CouchbaseConfigurations extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

       @Override
       public String getConnectionString() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
       }

       @Override
       public String getUserName() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return "Administrator";
       }

       @Override
       public String getPassword() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return "Administrator";
       }

       @Override
       public String getBucketName() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return "Users";
       }




   }
   ```

   When I try to start the application it throws following error, I tried to search many articles here and outside but they did not help

   ```
   Description:

   Field userRepository in com.mystery.controllers.MyController required a bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' that could not be found.
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
   The injection point has the following annotations:
       - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


   Action:

   Consider defining a bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' in your configuration.
   ```

   Any help would be appreciated, otherwise things seems good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised the issue with spring community and upgrading to a higher spring version resolved the issue
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1435

Answer (score 0):

see follow-up on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1435

Such a bean already exists.

Comment: I have only raised a support ticket :)